# get GET request in Golang on fcgi

Tags: post, get, go

I run my scripts under Apache. I understand how I can create request, for example:

```
http.Get(url)
```

How I can get GET request? I really dont see this information in docs. Thanks in advance!

UPD
For example, i do GET or POST-request to my go script from another script. In PHP I'd just write $a=$_GET["param"]. How i can do that in Go? Sorry for bad english, by the way

Comment: If you don't get answer, it might be because your question isn't really clear.

Comment: For example, i do GET or POST-request to my go script from another script. In PHP I'd just write $a=$_GET["param"]. How i can do that in Go? Sorry for bad english, by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handler is passed a [Request](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request). In that Request you find for example the parameters in the `Form` field as soon as you parsed it using [ParseForm](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm) :

```
    // Form contains the parsed form data, including both the URL
    // field's query parameters and the POST or PUT form data.
    // This field is only available after ParseForm is called.
    // The HTTP client ignores Form and uses Body instead.
    Form url.Values
```